# Error de ruta con subreportes en otros ordenadores

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

En el desarrollo de un sistema en Java he utilizado *iReport Designer 5.6.0* para generar algunos reportes.

Sin embargo, he tenido un inconveniente con los reportes que contienen subreportes. Tengo un reporte padre que a la vez contiene un subreporte que sería el detalle, en la vista previa en mi ordenador se muestra de maravilla y también al compilarlo, también funciona bien al crear el *.jar y usarlo en mi ordenador, pero al copiar este a otras maquinas no encuentra la ruta del subreporte, debido a esto no encuentra el subreporte.

La pregunta es como puedo enviar la ruta, la localización del subreporte al reporte padre.

Los dos reportes están en el mismo directorio de la aplicación.

El error generado en otros ordenadores es el siguiente:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : C:\Users\SONY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Proyecto\src\Reportes\pageheader.jasper

Esta ruta es donde se encuentra en mi ordenador.

El error que se visualiza es similar a este:
http://www.forosdelweb.com/f45/empaquetar-reportes-jar-1119897/

Answer (score 1):

Cuando hago uso de subreportes(en proyectos web), en el reporte padre, en las propiedades del subreporte pongo la propiedad `Connection type` a `$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}` y desde el código donde se llama lo hago así:

```
ServletContext sc = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
String reportePath = "/archivos/rptRequerimiento.jasper";
String subreportePath = sc.getRealPath("/archivos/");
subreportePath += "/";
Map parametros = new HashMap();
parametros.put("idRequerimiento", req.getIdRequerimiento());
parametros.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", subreportePath);
imprimePDF(reportePath, parametros, "reporteRequerimiento");
return null;
```

Desde allí le mando la ruta del subreporte, como parámetro.